# How to get the value of textfield in a tableview cell on click of a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview where user enters his social media profile urls. I want to get the value of that textfields on click of a button. The tableview is dynamic. I have attached the screenshot for reference. I am using Objective C to build up an iOs App and I am new to it. Any suggestions on how to do that? Thanks in advance.

[![This is the tableview with textfield in cell]

I have tried this :

```
NSMutableArray *Array = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i=0; i < getMYurl.count; i++){

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: i inSection: 0];

    SHOWURLTableViewCell *cellS = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableDictionary *Dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    UITextField *TextName= (UITextField*)[cellS.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
}
```

And my cellForRowAtIndexPath Method :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cellS  = (SHOWURLTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
//    cellS.labelDesc.text = mergeName;


    NSString *urlText = [[getMYurl valueForKey:@"url"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cellS.labelUrl.text = urlText;

    NSString *urlName = [[getMYurl valueForKey:@"url_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//    [urlMap setValue:mergeName forKey:urlText];

    cellS.urlNameET.tag = 100;
}
```

Comment: NSMutableArray *Array = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    for (int i=0; i < getMYurl.count; i++){
        
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: i inSection: 0];
        
        SHOWURLTableViewCell *cellS = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        
        NSMutableDictionary *Dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        
        UITextField *TextName= (UITextField*)[cellS.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    }

Comment: show your cellforRow method

Comment: You should have to store text of textfiled in any array variable (index wise) after end typing. Because tableview destroy the tableview cell while that was not showing into a screen.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya Ohk, Ill try that. Btw thanks..

Comment: can you explain what is url and url_name in getMYurl dict ?

Comment: @JenJose  getMyUrl dict is having the data which is being populated in the tableview before textlabel. (google, facebook etc)

Comment: @MehulVasa See my answer. And if that solves your problem then select as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to store text of textfiled in any array variable (index wise) after end typing. Because tableview destroy the tableview cell while that was not showing into a screen.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{       
          UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) textField.superview.superview;
          NSIndexPath *txtIndPath = [self.tblPendingDeliveryData indexPathForCell:cell];

          [myMutableArray insertObject:textField.text atIndex:txtIndPath.row];
    }
```

**Don't forgot to set delegate to textfield**

Comment: I had set the delegate as self on cell.textfield at cellForRowAt method and used your method but the array is blank.

Comment: Mark as the correct answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, the method is being called. I had putted a log in the method. The log gets printed.

Comment: how you declare array?

Comment: mergeAllData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: NSMutableArray * myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: just log the text of textfield into this method. Checks getting value of text or not?

Comment: I had a golbal variable named mergeAlldata of type NSMutableArray Like this : NSMutableArray *mergeAllData; And i had even logged the textfield.text it also appears to be blank. And even the txtIndPath is comming blank

Comment: Nup :(. i had also logged the value of txtIndPath. It is also comming blank. Had I declared the textfield delegate correctly?

Comment: show you structure of uitableview cell.
is format now?
TableviewCell->UIview->Textfield